# Can't insert long to SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I use these libraries:

- `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`
- `sqljdbc4.jar`

In SQLite the column type is `INTEGER`.

My Java code:

```
long tsMills = 123;
preparedStatement.setLong(parameterIndex, tsMills);
```

This inserts the data into the database correctly.

But if I use a `long` value like

```
long tsMills = 1522746908000l;
```

this value is *not* inserted into the DB.

How I can fix this?

Here all possible data types in SQLite:

[image]

Comment: What does "not inserted" actually mean for you?

Comment: In db the value is 0, but not 15227469080001

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite does not care much about types](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). It is very well possible to insert long values using Java.

With this library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.21.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and a database `test.db` with one table

```
create table warehouses(name string, capacity integer);
```

this Java code works as expected:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class InsertApp {

    private Connection connect() {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/test.db";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

    private void insert(String name, long capacity) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO warehouses(name,capacity) VALUES(?,?)";

        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            pstmt.setString(1, name);
            pstmt.setLong(2, capacity);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InsertApp app = new InsertApp();
        app.insert("Raw Materials", 3000000000L);
        app.insert("Semifinished Goods", 4000000000L);
        app.insert("Finished Goods", 5000000000L);
    }

}
```

After executing this code, the table has three rows with the expected values:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE warehouses(name string, capacity integer);
INSERT INTO "warehouses" VALUES('Raw Materials',3000000000);
INSERT INTO "warehouses" VALUES('Semifinished Goods',4000000000);
INSERT INTO "warehouses" VALUES('Finished Goods',5000000000);
COMMIT;
```